# ggplot - reorder_within - Order month

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting a bar graph. However, the axes x show in different month order. Using the command `reoder_within`, doesn't work for the purpose.

Follow below the ME.

```
ggplot(de, aes(fill=Cidade, y = Leitura  , x = Mes ))+geom_bar(position='dodge', stat='identity')
```

Generate the follow plot:

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs3my.png)

My purpose is modify the axes x to: Jan, Fev, March .....

The set of data is:

```
  Cidade    Mes       Leitura
  <chr>     <chr>       <dbl>
1 Petrolina Janeiro     74.2 
2 Petrolina Fevereiro   73.2 
3 Petrolina Março       68.7 
4 Petrolina Abril       42.9 
5 Petrolina Maio         9.84
6 Petrolina Junho        8.02
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `fct_inorder` here:

ggplot will order x axis alphapetically. To get the order in your table use `fct_inorder`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)
library(dplyr)

de %>% 
  mutate(Mes = fct_inorder(Mes)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(fill = Cidade, y = Leitura, x = Mes)) +
  geom_bar(position = 'dodge', stat = 'identity')
```

[image]